# python3.3 :transform string to dict

Tags: python

How to transform this string from str to dict?

```
s = "{'a':3, 'b':'user's test'}" # as per comment
s = decode()
a = dict()
a = eval(s)
```

It's not right! I can't use `eval()` or `exec()` to transform it. there is a `'` character in the string.

Comment: What makes you think `s` is in a format Python will recognize? It is not a proper dict literal, the extra quote is not the only problem here.

Comment: Nope - it's not right and not just because of the erroneous `'` in it... Where is this data coming from - why is it like that... at least give some more information...

Comment: `"{'a' : 3, 'b' : 'user\'s test'}"` would probably be safe to json.loads,  returning a dict.

Comment: sorry,i make a mistake

Comment: @TankorSmash: parser for original ambiguous grammar to convert to JSON left as an exercise for the reader?

Comment: the string s should be s = "{'a':3, 'b':'user's test'}"

Comment: Well, where you get that data from? Can you stop that source from being horribly broken?

Comment: the data is similar as "{'a':3, 'b':'user's test'}",i make a mistake when i asking question,so sorry.

Comment: Are you positive the one apostrophe wouldn't be escaped out with a slash?

Comment: i just get similar data from a redis server, and i want tranform it to  a dict.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't in this case, and it's not safe in general. `eval` allows arbitrary code execution and is prone to strange errors and security problems.

My suggestion is using a different serialization method, such as [`json`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html), which automatically escapes the strings as needed, or [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pickle.html), which converts Python objects into a binary representation.

Edit:
Besides, the syntax is wrong: dictionary key/values are separated by `:`, not `=`. So it should be `{'a': 3, 'b': 'user\'s test'}`, with the `'` escaped by a backslash.

Comment: We just have a string... if he could transform it to JSON or was at a stage he could use pickle - there wouldn't actually be a question... (not my downvote btw)

Comment: If all he had was that string, the solution would be trivial: `a = {'a': 3, 'b': 'user\'s test'}`. I always assume the given example is part of a more generic problem.

Comment: That's probably what he should have (or would like like)... if he can just type it in, it's not really a question... otherwise, it's more what is his data like... Currently it's not of a format that any standard library/function can utilise to get it into a type usable for anything...

Comment: Agree, the data as is it not usable as is. Which is exactly what I said in my answer, while mentioning alternative methods. I still don't get why the downvote.

Comment: My guess is that the question is asking "How do I get this string as a usable Python object" and your answer is saying use something else to start with and emphasising that the data they've got isn't valid - which the OP knows because that's why they're asking the question...

Comment: the string s should be s = "{'a':3, 'b':'user's test'}" ,so sorry, i type it wrong

Comment: I use json handle it right.thanks BoppreH. some one gave a downvote is not right, you have said my type mistake.